# How to add new setting fields to an existing setting page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

For a new Wordpress plugin development, I would like to add few custom fields in the exiting setting page of COD.
The examples I have found so far, most of them are creating a new setting page and adding setting fields there.
However I want to use existing COD setting page and add few more fields on the same setting page. How to achieve that ?

**Edit:**
Please note that I am trying to achieve that by writing a Wordpress plugin. I understand that it requires to use various Wordpress functions like register_setting(), setting_fields(), add_setting_section() etc. But the sequence they should be called is confusing. It is helpful if a sample example is provided.

Comment: You are talking about a COD settings page, so I presume this question is to do with WooCommerce? If so, please tag it with WooCommerce, so that the people who follow that tag can find it more easily to be able to help. Also, your question doesn't seem to be about a plugin, so you should delete that tag if its not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are some important links that describe how to add new menu-page/submenu-page/options etc :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages